# Google Tag Manager - event.preventdaulft using Custom HTML

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a question regarding Google Tag Manager. I am using a custom html tag with the following trigger -> Click Element, CSS Selector match, .className a

After the tag is triggered I want to prevent the link from opening since a contains href = "some url". I was thinking the only way is using event.preventDefault() . However it keeps telling me event is undefined.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi osman! Can you please provide the actual code? Also you might find this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't really work, because you do not have access to the actual link target.

Conceivably (I haven't really tested this) you can create a custom HTML tag to prevent the default action on the tag in advance, and attach it via [Tag Sequencing](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6238868) as the setup tag (i.e. a tag that is fired without a trigger of it's own) for your tracking tag:

```
document.querySelector('[href="/my/link/url"]').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```